# Actionscript works when tested in flash, but not on html page?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, addition

I am trying to create an ad for a website. When someone clicks on the ad, it is supposed to redirect them to a website, and register the click with google analytics.

I have done this with the following script:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

movieClip_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

    trace("hi");

    ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "test");
    //ExternalInterface.call("_gaq._trackPageview", "/vpv/annoncer/[firmanavn.dk]");

    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"), "_blank");
}
```

When i run this using preview->flash and i click on the surface, (where there is a big red square called movieClip_3) It opens the webpage. However when i try to publish as html, the big red square shows, but nothing happens on click. Not even console.log. I have tried setting allowscriptaccess = always but that does not change anything.

Can you guys help me? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `ExternalInterface.call("function(){console.log('test')}")` work?

Comment: try `ExternalInterface.call("javascript:console.log"`

Comment: Jeg "Hi" gets traced when i run it in flash locally, but console.log does not respond in any form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security problems?

> Developers should validate all URLs before passing them to this
>   function.
>
> For local content running in a browser, calls to the navigateToURL()
>   method that specify a "javascript:" pseudo-protocol (via a URLRequest
>   object passed as the first parameter) are only permitted if the SWF
>   file and the containing web page (if there is one) are in the
>   local-trusted security sandbox. Some browsers do not support using the
>   javascript protocol with the navigateToURL() method. Instead, consider
>   using the call() method of the ExternalInterface API to invoke
>   JavaScript methods within the enclosing HTML page.

source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()

**EDIT:**
Since javascript is not permitted out of the sandbox, you can try with `ExternalInterface`:

```
ExternalInterface.call("javascript_functionname", "mypage.html");
```

In the parameters for publishing:

```
'allowScriptAccess', 'always',
```

You can only test this on your server not locally.

Comment: Well i have no idea how to make sure the script swf is in the trusted security sandbox? And i am testing this in chrome, which should support this? I mean the navigateToUrl function is part of the standard snippets flash IDE offers? Should'nt it be supported? :/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest double checking the security settings (right click on flash container->Global Settings-> Advanced -> Trusted Location Settings). Also make sure your html file contains the javascript function you're trying to execute and look for blocked pop-up notifications in the browser. Maybe you just don't allow pop-ups to run.